# GetAvailableTextureMem equivalent in Direct3D 11

Tags: memory-management, textures, direct3d, direct3d11

I am looking for a possibility to get an estimation of the free texture memory in Direct3D, like it was possible using `IDirect3DDevice9::GetAvailableTextureMem`, but did not find anything so far. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code snippet:

```
int getAviableVideoMemoryInBytes(ID3D11Device* pd3dDevice)
{
    assert(pd3dDevice);

    IDXGIDevice * pDXGIDevice = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = pd3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void **)&pDXGIDevice);

    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to query interface IDXGIDevice" << std::endl;
    }

    IDXGIAdapter * pDXGIAdapter = nullptr;
    pDXGIDevice->GetAdapter(&pDXGIAdapter);

    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC adapterDesc;
    pDXGIAdapter->GetDesc(&adapterDesc);

    pDXGIDevice->Release();

    return adapterDesc.DedicatedVideoMemory;
}
```

Comment: OK, I did not know about this method. However, as I understand, this will give me the totally available memory not an estimate about how much is currently free, right?

Comment: Right. It determines the totally available memory and not the currently free memory.

Comment: Do you know whether the latter is possible, too?

Comment: No. I did some research about this myself, but I could not found any solution.